# Unhandled error "Cannot find context with specified id" using Robot framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I have a problem when working with iframe using Robot framework and Selenium2Library. It throws error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-
32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}
(Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

My test code is:

```
Fill In Description ${description}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${FRAME}    40
    Select Frame    ${FRAME}
    wait until page contains element  ${IFRAME BODY}
    Click Element    ${IFRAME BODY}
    wait until page contains element  ${IFRAME BODY}
    Clear Element Text    ${IFRAME BODY}
    wait until page contains element  ${IFRAME BODY}
    Input Text    ${IFRAME BODY}     ${description}
    Unselect Frame
```

It fails in step `Input Text    ${IFRAME BODY}     ${description}`

Btw I reuse this keyword for more pages where this iframe occurs but it fails only in once exact case - but the html code is the same for all the iframes, so really dont understand why it works just sometimes..

Will be glad for any help.

Comment: what does `${IFRAME BODY}` represent? By the name it sounds like an iframe element or the body inside an iframe, in which case I don't understand why you're trying to input text into an iframe (versus an input element).

Comment: The structure in html is: <iframe><html><body></body></html></iframe> and the <body> element is the one which stands for "input field", there is no other element inside..thats why I am trying to input into <body> element...and as I mentioned, it works in 2 cases, but does not work in 1 case...

Comment: what do you think should happen when you input text into something that isn't designed to take text?

Comment: well, obviously it types the text into the body element - really works for 2 out of my 3 cases (pages with iframes)...just in one it does not, and I really don't know why because the code behind that is the same..

Comment: I just had the same error message on a test script.  The exception is thrown on this line: `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,myxpath)))`  Similar to what @neliCZka is reporting, it sometimes hangs on this line, which is re-iterated several times, but most other times, it works fine. I wish I knew how this error is different than, say, an "element not found" error or a "timeout" error.

Comment: Are you seeing the same problem when using a different browser? Just to narrow the search for the solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this error message is being [generated by Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20820) instead of Selenium or Robot. I'm having the same problem with puppeteer + Chrome, so a generic, non-Selenium answer would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to change the code like this to work in other frame:

```
Log comment ${comment}
   wait until element is visible    ${RICH TEXT AREA}    40
   sleep   1
   click element    ${RICH TEXT AREA}
   Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${FRAME}    40
   Select Frame    ${FRAME}
   wait until element is visible    ${IFRAME BODY}   20
   input text   ${IFRAME BODY}   ${comment}
   Unselect Frame
```

`${IFRAME BODY}` is still `//body` in Iframe and surprisingly it inputs the text all the time now...
And unfortunately it does not work without sleep :( But with sleep it works..

Comment: What change did you make? I'm getting the same error message with [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) against Chrome, but I this code is a wall of text to me. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know really, I just added implicit wait (sleep) and I did some clicking into the element in which the iframe exists before I access the iframe itself. It is also possible that it started working due to higher version of chrome driver.

Answer (score 11):

This issue seems to be reemerging in chromedriver, latest one being: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2198

According to this ticket can be fixed in two ways:

- switch to chromedriver version which does not have this issue
- add wait after switching to frame

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Thanks for including the relevant info in your post!